# Method returning a bool on not exists from two lists of different types

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write a method which will return a bool based on two lists.

`loadedBillSites` - The first list is of type `List<string>`, this is a list of site numbers that have been read in from a CSV.

`storedSites` - The second list is of type `MyModel` which contains around 10 properties, one of which a string called `SiteNumber`.

My method currently looks like this:

```
public bool AreSitesStored()
{
    var loadedBillSites = _invoiceRepository.GetAllBillSites(path).Distinct().ToList(); //read file in, return list of sites contained in file

    var storedSites = _siteRepository.GetAllSites(); //get all known sites from database

    //return false if loadedBillSites contains anything 'unknown' to the system
}
```

I'm struggling to compare the `storedsites.SiteNumber` with the `loadedBillSites` list. I've attempted to use the `Linq.Except` method but I'm seeing extension method errors, and cannot get a handle on the `SiteNumber`.

```
    var unknownSites = loadedBillSites.Except(); //<- storedSites.SiteNumber?

    if (unknownSites.count > 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
```

Is there a way of achieving what I want easily?

Comment: Do you want to see if they are equal?

Comment: possibly? `loadedBillSites.Except(storedSites.Select(x=>x.SiteNumber))`

Comment: I don't care if they are equal, if the storedSites has 200 sites in its list, and loadedBillSites has 5 but one of them is not stored already, then I want to return false, as the file contains not stored data so the user needs to resolve this first.

Comment: Did you read the manual for [`Enumerable.Except`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb300779.aspx)?

Comment: @poke yes I've already looked here, I find msdn hard to digest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load the known site numbers to a list like this:

```
var knownSiteNumbers = storedSites.Select(x => x.SiteNumber).ToList();
```

And then use the `Any` method to see if any of the items in `loadedBillSites` do not exist in the list of known site numbers like this:

```
bool unknownSites = loadedBillSites.Any(x => !knownSiteNumbers.Contains(x));
```

If the lists are large, you can use a `HashSet` instead of a list to store the known site numbers like this:

```
var knownSiteNumbers =
    new HashSet<string>(storedSites.Select(x => x.SiteNumber));

bool unknownSites =
    loadedBillSites.Any(x => !knownSiteNumbers.Contains(x));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this:

`return loadedBillSites.Except(storedSites.Select(x=>x.SiteNumber)).Any();`

Answer (score 0):

It depends if your list `storedSites` is of type `MyModel` or `List<MyModel>`.

**Case 1: `storedSites` is of type `MyModel`**

```
bool notExists = !loadedBillSites.Any(s => s == MyModel.SiteNumber);
```

**Case 2: `storedSites` is of type `List<MyModel>`**

In that case, use @yacoub-massab's complete answer.